# Is semi-unlocked BitLocker drive data fully decrypted?

Tags: windows, ssd, bitlocker, filesystem-corruption

My BitLocker encrypted SSD went corrupt after I started to decrypt it. Is my data on the SSD still encrypted? It was in the early stages of the BitLocker decryption and the drive was never fully decrypted (maybe about 25%) What happens after we begin to decrypt a BitLocker encrypted drive?

Comment: Based on what you describe only the data that was decrypted would not be encrypted, but based on that state, you wouldn’t be able to access any of the data on the drive anyways

Comment: I can't access. but there is so much sensitive data on that hard drive and I wanna make sure before I send it to warranty service

Comment: If Windows wasn't on that SSD and it does boot, try [this software](https://www.m3datarecovery.com/bitlocker-drive-data-recovery/data-recovery-after-bitlocker-drive-encryption-interuption.html).